# How to render a block/template after page load

Tags: layout, template, magento2.3.1, magento2-enterprise

I need to know whether we can render a block or a phtml template file after the page load.

I have added the block and template file in the layout file and it works fine.

But i dont want that data to be loaded at the beginning. I want that block to be rendered after the page load.

Is there anything that can be done in xml layout file to load the block after the page loads?

Comment: have you created the xml as custom module?

Comment: @aravind yes i have created layout xml file and its template and block file in a separate module

Comment: You need Js file to load after page load..Create custom js file in your module and use ajax method and create a controller to call that phtml file. In ajax success You can put that html variable where you want..

Comment: @aravind I totally understood your approach, even i thought of the same earlier. But how to make that custom js to load after the page load.

Comment: Do you know how to call controller using ajax and return phtml file ?

Comment: Yes i know, But regarding js i dont know how to call that js after the page load

Answer (score 0):

In you Js file ,Check whether it is loading after page load

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'domReady!'
  ], function ($) {
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       //Your Ajax code
      });
});
```